# c code to print reverse of array using recurion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

This code is to print reverse of array using recursion
I am using recursion function called from main
output should be as 5,4,3,2,1
can someone help in debugging this

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recursion(int a[])
{
    int i=0;

    if(i<5)
    return;

    i++;
    recursion(i);
    printf("%d ",a[i]);

}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,4,5};
    recursion(arr);
}
```

Comment: Why would you use recursion when there is no need to?
Simply print it backwards with a for loop

Comment: Likely because this is a homework exercise..  just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

A good C book is needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recursion(int a[], int i, int size)
{
    if(i < size -1)
        recursion(a, i + 1, size);
    printf("i = %d arr[%d] == %d \n",i, i, a[i]);

}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 4, 5};
    recursion(arr, 0, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `recursion` function is not working properly.
Note whenever you are calling a function the `parameters` should be same. In your code parameter of your function is array, but when you are calling it from inside the function i.e `recursion` you are passing `i`.

So, what you can do is that

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recursion(int a[], int i)
{
  int t = i-1;
  if(t>=0)
  {
      printf("%d ",a[t]);
      return recursion(a, t);
  }

}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,4,5};
    recursion(arr,4);
}
```

Hopefully that helps